# Iterate list and utilize matches() regex in jenkins groovy pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following code which looks at the entries in the blacklist.txt file snd blacklists the entries.

```
      String blacklist = readFile file: "${WORKSPACE}/blacklist.txt"
      def instances = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/ec2_instances.json"
      instances.each {
        if(it.Id) {
          it.each {
            if (blacklist.contains(it.Name)) {
              println 'The instance ' + it.Name + 'is blacklisted and will not be killed'
            } else {
              println 'Triggering killer job to terminate instance ' + it.Name + '-' + it.Id
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I would like to use regex against `Name` in the code. To do this, I understand I can use `matches` instead of `contains`.
However, I cannot seem to find the correct syntax to add the regex.
This is what I have tried:

```
      String blacklist = readFile file: "${WORKSPACE}/blacklist.txt"
      def instances = readJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/ec2_instances.json"
      instances.each {
        if(it.Id) {
          it.each {
            if (blacklist.matches(it.Name(.*))) {
              println 'The instance ' + it.Name + 'is blacklisted and will not be killed'
            } else {
              println 'Triggering killer job to terminate instance ' + it.Name + '-' + it.Id
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Note the added attempt at regex `(.*)`.

This fails.

What is the correct way to do this within this script?

Answer (score 0):

Your code tries to call it.Name as if it was a function. You need to make a string:

```
blacklist.matches("${it.Name}(.*)")
```